# If $rk J=0$ then $R$ is a field

Tags: ring-theory

If $R$ is a regular local ring with maximal ideal $J$ and $rk J=0$ why is $R$ then a field?

I have this as a statement in my notes and I feel that it should be obvious but I have no idea why it is the case.

Is it because as the ring is regular we have $dim J/J^2=0$ and hence $J=J^2$ and so $J$ must be equal to $0$ for some reason? I could use Nakayama's Lemma to show this if $J$ was f.g. but I can't see why that is the case.

Comment: What do you mean by "$rkJ=0\;$"? The size (zero!) of a minimal number of generators of $\;J\;$ ? Because if you do then your question is trivial...

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I think you meant

$$\text{rk}\,J=0\iff \dim J/J^2=0\iff J=J^2\implies J=0\;\;\text{by Nakayama's Lemma}$$

and we're done.

Comment: By $rk J$ i mean the rank, or height of $J$- the maximal length chain of primes. But can't we only use Nakayama's Lemma if $J$ if finitely generated? How do we know that this is the case?

Comment: $\;R\;$ is regular $\;\iff R\;$ is Noetherian, by definition...

Comment: Ah ok thanks, always helps if I can get definitions right!